# Popular VSelect (Vuetify) com dados vindo da API usando VueJs 3

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Olá, estou com problemas para conseguir popular um v-select do vuetify (VueJs 3) com dados vindo de uma api em laravel, quando tento popular aparece o seguinte erro no console:

[image: erro do console]

[image: warning que aparece quando abro o select]

Html do select

```
<VSelect
 v-model="nomeResponsavel" 
 items="usuarios"
 item-title="name"
 item-value="id"  
 >
```

Array onde eu tento colocar os dados

```
let usuarios = [{}]
```

Requisição axios dos dados

```
  axios.get(`usuario`)
    .then(res => {
      usuarios = res.data.data
    })
}
```

Hook usado para chamar a função

```
onMounted(() => {
  getUsers()
})
```

O resultado final é apenas um select vazio:

[image: select sem os dados]

Comment: vale dizer que a requisição está sendo feita com sucesso, os dados estão sendo retornados normalmente, porém na hora de popular o select com os dados está dando erro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que percebi você está utilizando a API de composição, tente algo como:

```
import { ref } from 'vue'

let usuarios = ref([])
```

Utilizar o ref para tornar o seu dado reativo.

E corrija:

```
function getUsers(){
  axios.get(`usuario`)
    .then(res => {
      usuarios.value = res.data.data
    })
}
```

Uma vez que seu dado está reativo utilizando o ref, altere o value dele:

Após isso antes de colocar no v-select para verificar se o seu dado está sendo populado, tente algo assim no seu template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{usuarios}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Veja se está sendo exibido corretamente os valores, estando corretamente, você garante que a variável está sendo preenchida.

Por fim, no componente do vuetify, corrija o bind do atributo items, ficando assim :items="usuarios", da forma que está, você está passando a string usuários para o items e não uma variável:

```
<VSelect
 v-model="nomeResponsavel" 
 :items="usuarios"
 item-title="name"
 item-value="id"  
 >
```

Comment: muito obrigado! consegui resolver fazendo assim.